# How to extract data from a text file

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse some large text file and extract `Display name` and `area code` only if it matches the following pattern:

- Line starts with `display name` (any number of words, but cannot contain digits or special characters)
- Followed by 6 digits (can contain spaces)
- Followed by `#text` tag

**Input file**

```
John doe 123 456 #text some text
Test 123456 #text
Test$test 123456 #text
Test123 345678 #text
Test 123 #test
Test 123456 #test1
Test 123g45 #test
```

**Input and expected output**

```
John doe 123 456 #text some text
Display name: John doe
Area code: 123 456

Test 123456 #text
Display name: Test
Area code: 123456

Test$test 123456 #text
Invalid, display name contains special character

Test123 345678 #text
Invalid, display name contains digits

Test 123 #test
Invalid, area code contains only 3 digits

Test 123456 #test1
Invalid, contains invalid tag

Test 123g45 #test
Invalid, area code contains letters
```

etc.

I know how to open the text file and read it line by line, but having trouble with writing the regular expression.

This is what I have tried:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "John Doe 123 45 #text Lorem ipsum dolor :)";
    string pattern = @"(\w+)*([0-9]{2,5}).([0-9]{2,5}).#text";
    Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        string key = match.Groups[0].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(key);
    }
}
```

edit:

Here's some more explanation

**Display name**
Display name can contain any number of words, e.g.
`John Michael Smith` is valid because `John` is the first name, `Michael` is the middle name and `Smith` is the surname. `Šljaker` is also valid display name because it's someone's nickname and it may contain non-English characters. But names with numbers are not valid eg. `John1`. Why? That's our business rule, no numbers :) I guess that `\w` will work here, and `a-zA-Z` won't because it won't cover non-English letters.

**Area code**
Business rule is simple: it must contain 6 numbers, and we don't care how they are formatted.
All these are valid area codes: 123456, 12 34 56, 1234 56, etc. Regex doesn't need to trim spaces, I will handle this in code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you need to extract (for your example, what result do you want do get ?)

Comment: @Superbest, I've edited my question, but obviously my regex is very wrong :(

Comment: Oh, I assume your text file is only composed of this kind of lines : John doe 123 456 #text some text, Test 123456 #test1 ?

Comment: @aurel.g, yes, that's correct. In examples I showed how the line may look like, what's the desired output, or why the line contains invalid data.

Comment: @šljaker: What can we assume about the display name?

Comment: @nhahtdh, any number of words, it cannot contain numbers or special characters. So `nhahtdh` is valid, `John Doe` is also valid, but `nhahtdh123` is not valid since it contains `123`.

Comment: @šljaker: How about Unicode character and space (space is known from the example, but not your description)? How about `_`? If you can specify clearly the set of allowed characters, then you can write the regex easily.

Comment: Can you explain the 6 digits (can contain spaces) further? How many spaces are allowed? Are they always in the same spots if they exist?

Comment: @Oded yeah that would help alot. If there is only one space, my combination does work. (since it's derived from your regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification of the input is still a bit vague to write a proper regular expression. Before writing the regular expression, it is necessary to get the specification down, or at least make assumptions that will work for your current set of data.

This is the regex that I wrote, the regex will validate the whole line. Assumption comes later.

```
^([a-zA-Z ]+)(?<! ) +((?:[0-9] *){6}) *#text( .*)?$
```

I only allow spaces (ASCII 32) in the input. You can replace spaces in the regex with `\s` if you want to allow tabs and other whitespace characters.

`([a-zA-Z ]+)(?<! ) +`: Match and capture the display name. Only English alphabets and spaces are allowed in the display name. The `(?<! )` is there to suppress trailing space from the capturing group; it has another effect of disallowing name with only spaces. If you want to allow any letter in Unicode to match, use `[\p{L} ]+` in place of `[a-zA-Z ]+`.

`((?:[0-9] *){6})`: exactly 6 decimal digits, separated by arbitrary amount of spaces. It will not allow number stuck to the display name, due to the matching of 1 space or more  `+` before this piece.

`*#text( .*)?`: I allow the numbers to stick to the tag (e.g. `Name 123456#text dfsjhdf`); change it to `+#text( .*)?` to disallow this. `( .*)?` makes sure there is a space after `#text` if there are more comment, or nothing follows `#text` (e.g. `Name 123456 #text`).

The captured text from this regex will:

- Display name: May contain excessive leading space and spaces in between, but no trailing space. At least one English alphabet.
- Area code: Contains **exactly** 6 digits. There may be arbitrary spaces in between, so you may want to process the matched string.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your `regex` returns matches for this text `John Doe Smith 12 3456 #text3 Test` even though it contains `text3` tag and not just `text` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the regex pattern with the following:

```
@"^([\D]+)\s*((?:\d\s*?){6})\s*\#text\s*(.*)$"
```

This searches for, in order

- A sequence of non-digits (Group 1)
- Followed by any number of spaces
- Followed by exactly 6 numbers, each followed optionally by spaces (Group 2)
- Followed by any number of spaces and the literal "#text" followed optionally by spaces
- Followed by the rest of the line (Group 3)

Since this is being evaluated against many lines, consider adding the `RegexOptions.Compiled` flag (i.e.: `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled`).

Display name is stored as `match.Groups[1].Value`; area code as `match.Groups[2].Value`, and text as `match.Groups[3].Value`.

Comment: Thanks!  Your regex returns matches for this text `John Doe Smith 12 3456 #text3 Test` even though it contains `text3` tag and not just `text` tag

Comment: The regex will allow invalid cases such as `;;;;; 123456 #text`